# How to set different range for minimum range (from) and maximum range (to) in nouislider?

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-ui, nouislider

I need to set different custom ranges for minimum & maximum side

Below is my sample code.

```
rangeConfig: any = {
        behaviour: 'drag',
        connect: true,
        snap: true,
        range: {
            min: 2,
            '3.33%':5,
            '6.66%':6,
            '9.99%':8,
            '13.32%':9,
            '16.65%':11,
            '19.98%':12,
            '23.31%':14,
            '26.64%':15,
            '29.97%':17, etc..
            max:100
        },
        tooltips: [new RangeFormatter, new RangeFormatter],
    };

export class RangeFormatter implements NouiFormatter {
        rangeToFormats: any = {2:2, 6:6, 9:9, 12:12, 15:15, 18:18, 21:21, 25:25, 30:30, 35:35, 40:40, 45:45, 50:50, 55:55, 100:'65+'};
        rangeFromFormats: any = {5:5, 8:8, 11:11, 14:14, 17:17, 20:20, 24:24, 29:29, 34:34, 39:39, 44:44, 49:49, 54:54, 64:64, 100:'65+'};
        to(value: number): string {
            return this.rangeToFormats[value];
        }

        from(value: string): number {
            return this.rangeFromFormats[value];
        }
    }
```

We need slider with left knob of the slider can be set to any of the **low values : 2, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 65+** 
and right knob can be set to any of the **high values: 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 24, 29, 34, 39, 44, 49, 54, 64, 65+**

I am using ng-nouislider in angular 5. Is there any solution to differentiate ranges for minimum (from side) and maximum (to side)?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "left & right side"?

Comment: @Lg102, I mean "to" & "from" slide button.

Comment: @Lg102, I have updated question details

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is pretty close, you just need some tweaks.

- Since both your spans have 14 values, set your slider range from `0 ... 13`
- Instead of passing the formatters to the `tooltips` option, pass it to the `format` option so it applies to the whole slider
- Provide two different formatters, one for each handle, that map the values `0 ... 13` to your desired values